# Fill the intersection of two fields of views - better looking figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I started with this sort of field of view of two cameras in different positions but pointing in the same scene.

I'm interested in demonstrating the intersection of the two fields of views. Later on I'll move one of the cameras with respect to the other.

Anyone would suggest how to start that and any other suggestions are also appreciated in terms of style, looking..etc

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1.0,
    %Option for nice arrows
    >=stealth, %
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,%
    axis/.style={thick,->},
    wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth},
    polaroid/.style={fill=black!60!white, opacity=0.3},
]
    % Colors
    \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightgreen}{green!80!black}
    \colorlet{darkred}{red!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightred}{red!80!black}

    % Frame
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(10, 0,   0) node [right] {x};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  10, 0) node [right] {y};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  0,   7) node [above] {z};

    \draw[thick,dashed] (-2,0,0) -- (O);


    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$A(0,0,5)$}] (A) at (0,0,5);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{$B(2,0,2)$}] (B) at (0,5,5);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{$C(0,3,3)$}] (C) at (0,5,0);
    \coordinate[label=above left:{$D(5,0,0)$}] (D) at (8,2,0);

    \coordinate[label=above left:{$E(5,0,0)$}] (E) at (8,7,0);

    \fill[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.1] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (O)-- cycle;

    \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (O);
    \draw[blue] (A) -- (D) -- (B);

    \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (E) -- (O);
    \draw[blue] (A) -- (E) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

This a new version, thanks to @marsupilam

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(0.866cm,-0.5cm)}, y={(0.866cm,0.5cm)}, z={(0cm,1cm)}, scale=1.0,
    %Option for nice arrows
    >=stealth, %
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=2pt,%
    axis/.style={thick,->},
    wave/.style={thick,color=#1,smooth},
    polaroid/.style={fill=black!60!white, opacity=0.3},
]
    % Colors
    \colorlet{darkgreen}{green!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightgreen}{green!80!black}
    \colorlet{darkred}{red!50!black}
    \colorlet{lightred}{red!80!black}

    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (B) at (0,0,4);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (C) at (0,5,4);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (D) at (0,5,0);

    \coordinate[label=above right:{Caméra}] (O1) at (8,2,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{Lumière}] (O2) at (6,7,-2);

    % Frame
    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(15, 0,   0) node [right] {x};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  20, 0) node [right] {y};
    \draw[axis] (O) -- +(0,  0,   7) node [above] {z};

    \draw[thick,dashed] (-2,0,0) -- (O);

    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.9] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

    \path [name path =pC] (O1) -- (C) ;
    \path [name path =pD] (O1) -- (D) ;
    \path [name path =pA] (O2) -- (A) ;
    \path [name path =pB] (O2) -- (B) ;

    \path 
      [name intersections={of=pC and pB, by={iT}}]
      [name intersections={of=pA and pD, by={iB}}] ;

    \begin{scope}[transparency group,inside/.style={fill=green!50!pink,very thick, fill opacity=.2}]
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (iB) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iB) -- (A) -- (D) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (iB)  -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
      \foreach \p/\q in {C/D,D/A,A/B,B/C} 
      {
        \draw[green!70!black,thick,fill,fill opacity=.1] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O2) ;
        \draw[pink!70!black,very thick,fill=pink,fill opacity=.5] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O1) ;
      }
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (C)-- (B)-- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (iB);      
      \draw[inside] (A) -- (D);      
      \draw[inside] (iB) -- (D)-- (C)-- (B) -- (A) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (A2) at (0,10,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (B2) at (0,10,4);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (C2) at (0,15,4);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{}] (D2) at (0,15,0);    

    \coordinate[label=above right:{Caméra}] (O12) at (8,12,0);
    \coordinate[label=above right:{Lumière}] (O22) at (0,20,-2);    

    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.5] (A2) -- (B2) -- (C2) -- (D2) -- cycle;    

    \path [name path =pC2] (O12) -- (C2) ;
    \path [name path =pD2] (O12) -- (D2) ;
    \path [name path =pA2] (O22) -- (A2) ;
    \path [name path =pB2] (O22) -- (B2) ;

    \path 
      [name intersections={of=pC2 and pB2, by={iT2}}]
      [name intersections={of=pA2 and pD2, by={iB2}}] ;

    \begin{scope}[transparency group,inside/.style={fill=green!50!pink,very thick, fill opacity=.2}]
      \draw[inside] (iT2) -- (iB2) -- (D2) -- (C2) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iB2) -- (A2) -- (D2) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iT2) -- (iB2)  -- (A2) -- (B2) -- cycle;
      \foreach \p/\q in {C2/D2,D2/A2,A2/B2,B2/C2} 
      {
        \draw[green!70!black,thick,fill,fill opacity=.1] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O22) ;
        \draw[pink!70!black,very thick,fill=pink,fill opacity=.5] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O12) ;
      }
      \draw[inside] (iT2) -- (C2)-- (B2)-- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iT2) -- (iB2);      
      \draw[inside] (A2) -- (D2);      
      \draw[inside] (iB2) -- (D2)-- (C2)-- (B2) -- (A2) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious : does the intersection of two fields of view have any particular interest or property in optics or some other domain of physics / engineering ?

Comment: Erf. I guess it's just the set of points that can be seen by both cameras, so that would be useful to know for 3d cams...

Comment: @marsupilam in fact one is a camera and the other is light. I'm conducting some experiments with polarization light to show that there's a different in terms of image quality when the volume of intersection is reduced

Comment: @marsupilam I've edited my post

Comment: Actually, the transparency group may be useless (and thus also the scope...) Also, I don't think the geometry is accurate if the light source and the cam are not at the same height (not quite sure what it should look like...) And you don't need tikz-3dplot if you are using it (like here). The point was to not hard-code the 3d-viewpoint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a try.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

%% viewing angles %%
\def\angThe{70}
\def\angPhi{55}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{\angThe}{\angPhi}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5]

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,0,5);
    \coordinate (C) at (0,5,5);
    \coordinate (D) at (0,5,0);

    \coordinate (O1) at (8,2,0);
    \coordinate (O2) at (8,7,0);

    \draw[fill=blue,fill opacity=0.9] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;

    \path [name path =pC] (O1) -- (C) ;
    \path [name path =pD] (O1) -- (D) ;
    \path [name path =pA] (O2) -- (A) ;
    \path [name path =pB] (O2) -- (B) ;

    \path 
      [name intersections={of=pC and pB, by={iT}}]
      [name intersections={of=pA and pD, by={iB}}] ;

    \begin{scope}[transparency group,inside/.style={fill=purple,very thick, fill opacity=.2}]
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (iB) -- (D) -- (C) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iB) -- (A) -- (D) -- cycle;
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (iB)  -- (A) -- (B) -- cycle;
      \foreach \p/\q in {C/D,D/A,A/B,B/C} 
      {
        \draw[green!70!black,thick,fill,fill opacity=.1] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O2) ;
        \draw[pink!70!black,very thick,fill=pink,fill opacity=.4] (\p) -- (\q) -- (O1) ;
      }
      \draw[inside] (iT) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```